# Get Last 30 days data from table where date is "DDMMMYYYY"

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with column as DDMMMYYYY (20JUN2018), from this table how can i subtract and get last 10 days or 30 days data from the table?

Comment: Show us the attempts you made to solve this problem.

Comment: First you need cast it as a date (some substringin' and castin' you can look up yourself.) Then hive has a date_sub function. (which you can also look up yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp` to convert the date to `yyyy-MM-dd` format and  use `date_add` on the result.

```
where dateCol >= date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20JUN2018','ddMMMyyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),-30)
and dateCol < current_date
```